# Factory Girl Trait not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have model `Address`, which has a mandatory attribute zip code and two others -- `latitude` and `longitude`.

Every time `Address` is created, `latitude` and `longitude` are retrieved via Geocoder gem and stored. The address is considered valid when it has `latitude` and `longitude`.

I'm trying to create addresses with FactoryGirl and Faker and I want to generate zip codes until `latitude` and `longitude` have values.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    begin
      zipcode { Faker::Address.zip }
    end while latitude.nil? || longitude.nil?
  end
end
```

When I run tests using addresses I got this error:

> Trait not registered: latitude.

Comment: Do you need exact coordinates for the fake zipcode? Can't you just initialize them with fake data, too, with something like `latitude { Faker::Address.latitude }` and `longitude { Faker::Address.longitude}` ?

Comment: Let's summarize what this approach will cause :every time you will create an address in your test, it will generate 2-3 http calls. That will make your test incredibly slow and as a result, you (or your co-workers) will get fed of running those at some point. This will most likely lead to drop in test coverage and tones of technical debt. On top of that, your tests will not work when you work off-line and can break randomly if the service is unavailable. Solution? Don't make any http calls in tests.